# Toggle Button With Props & emit

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, toggle, vue-props, v-model

this is my first time using props and I can't figure out what's the problem

I want to make a component of the toggle button and then use it anywhere with an entry data,
but it doesn't work as I expect
could you please help me to fix this?
here is my component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label v-for="(label, option) in options" :key="option">
      <input
        type="radio"
        :value="option"
        :checked="option = value"
        @change="$emit('input', option)"
      />
      <slot :name="option">
      {{ label }}
    </slot>
    </label>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ToggleSwitch',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    options: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and here is where I want to use this button :

```
  <toggle-switch v-model="value" :options="options">
  <template #Single>
  <p>test slot</p>
  </template>
  <template #Subscription>
  <p>test slot2</p>
  </template>
  </toggle-switch>
<script>
import ToggleSwitch from '../components/ToggleSwitch.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    ToggleSwitch,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: 'Single',
      users: useUsersListStore(),
    }
  },
  computed: {
    options() {
      return {
        Single: 'ggg',
        Subscription: 'bbb',
      }
    }
  },
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are emiting events from child components using "emit", but your parent component isn't listening to those events.

First option is to add listener where the component is used.
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events

Second option is to use two-way data binding between parent and child component.
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html

Answer (score 0):

a same radio name is required when you want toggle item, and :checked="option == value" not :checked="option = value"

```js
  <template>
      <div>
        <label v-for="(label, option) in options" :key="option">
          <input
            type="radio" :name="name"
            :value="option"
            :checked="option == value"
            @change="$emit('input', option)"
          />
          <slot :name="option">
          {{ label }}
        </slot>
        </label>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'ToggleSwitch',
      props: {
        value: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        options: {
          type: Object,
          required: true
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
//to use 
<toggle-switch v-model="value" name="testname" :options="options">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, selecting the options working properly with your changes but still there is a problem in my console "Missing required prop: "value""  and I can't see options value in buttons

Comment: because you've defined a prop named `value` in your ToggleSwitch component, made it required, and then didn't bind any `value` prop in your parent component.  You only have `v-model` and `options`.  By default, v-model binds to a prop named [modelValue](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) in the child component, not `value`.  You need to rename it

Comment: @m.ma Just delete :value="option" ,It has no use

Comment: m.ma yoduh thank you very much , I'm very new